# @Before not setting up data during integration test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I am creating an integraiton test for a JpaRepository and the testcase fails with "Record not found with random value rand", as null is returned in the find results.

My test case:

```
@SpringBootTest
class JpatestsApplicationTests {

@Autowired
private JpaRepo jpaRepo;

@Before
void setup() {
    FirstTable firstTable1 = new FirstTable();
    firstTable1.setUid("x");
    firstTable1.setRandom("rand");
    jpaRepo.save(firstTable1);
}

@Test
void testFindByRandom() {
    FirstTable f = jpaRepo.findByRandom("rand");//find by random value 'rand'
    Assert.notNull(f, "Record not found with random value rand ");
}
```

The entity associated:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class FirstTable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    private String uid;

    @Column
    private String random;
```

And my Repository:

```
    @Repository
    public interface JpaRepo extends JpaRepository<FirstTable, Long> {

    FirstTable findByRandom(String rand); 
   }
```

I am using h2 database.
Why is the result coming as null for findByRandom? Also please note that if I move the record saving part  `jpaRepo.save(firstTable1)` to be within the test case (before the findByRandom("rand") is called, it gets passed.

Why wouldn't it work if I save the record in setup() method annotated with @Before ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `@Transactional` on the top of your class.

`@Transactional` will cause your tests to execute within a test-managed transaction that will be rolled back after the test completes; code executed within the `@Before` method will be executed inside the test-managed transaction.

Comment: Added @Transactional, still getting the same error. Any property updates required?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of spring-boot-test makes use of junit 5 and @Before is deprecated. It started working after changing to `@BeforeAll` with annotation of `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` at the class level
My updated test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class JpatestsApplicationTests {

@Autowired
private JpaRepo jpaRepo;

@BeforeAll
void setup() {
    FirstTable firstTable1 = new FirstTable();
    firstTable1.setUid("x");
    firstTable1.setRandom("rand");
    jpaRepo.save(firstTable1);
}

@Test
void testFindByRandom() {
    FirstTable f = jpaRepo.findByRandom("rand");//find by random value 'rand'
    Assert.notNull(f, "Record not found with random value rand ");
}
```

Chose BeforeAll over BeforeEach as I need to run it only once during execution of this class.
Reference: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/